# Angularjs reports "Cannot set property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting an error that says "cannot set property of undefined".

```
vm.dtr1 = {}; // maybe I'm initializing this wrong ?
vm.dtr1.date1 = {}; // maybe I'm initializing this wrong ?

for(var x=0; x<5; x++){
  vm.dtr1[x].date1 = new Date(days[x]); //getting undefined value
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to be an array, then before assigning a property it must be initialized.

```
vm.dtr1 = []; // make it an array

for(var x=0; x<5; x++) {
   vm.dtr1[x] = {}; // initialize it first
   vm.dtr1[x].date1 = new Date(days[x]);
}
```

Or in better way

```
vm.dtr1 = [];

for(var x=0; x<5; x++) {
   vm.dtr1[x] = { date1:  new Date(days[x])};
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. its working now i've used your second answer

Comment: The second is better. In the first I just want to show the initialization

Answer (score 3):

**`vm.dtr`** is an object, but you are trying to use it as an array by accessing the index. Which will obviously undefined.

You need to declare vm.dtr as an array of type **dtx**.

Comment: I've tried to change `vm.dtr1 = []` but it still throwing the error.

Comment: just doing that won't work, you need to have the objects of type dtx

Answer (score 1):

Try following changes will suely work

```
vm.dtr1 = []; // change here
//vm.dtr1.date1 = {}; // remove this

for(var x=0; x<5; x++){
  vm.dtr1[x] ={}
  vm.dtr1[x].date1 = new Date(days[x]); //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the possible values of `x` are not correct keys for `vm.dtr1`.

You may want to use `for...in` loop instead:

```
for(var x in vm.dtr1) {
  if (vm.dtr1.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
    vm.dtr1[x] = new Date(days[x]);
  }
}
```

I still don't know what `days` is. So, you need to figure that out. For more details about iterating over an object, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to do it like this

```
var vm = {}; vm.dtr1 = []; 
var day = ['7/7/2012','7/7/2012','7/7/2012','7/7/2012','7/7/2012']
  vm.dtr1[x] = {};
  vm.dtr1[x].date1 = new Date(days[x]);
}
```

Still don't know what days is, i did is as expected input for Date constructor